# How to pass build Query string to the Nest Client

Tags: c#, nest

I am adding a *ElasticSearch* query syntax to a *JSON* object and passing a parameter and build the actual query string.
I am using `GetElasticSearchQuery` method to build desired query and its working fine.

My question is how to update this querystring to *ElasticSearch* client directly. I have tried few options to pass the buildquery. But its not working.  Is there a way to use the buildquery as a argument in *Nest* client.
How to update the *ElasticSearch* client to use that buildquery?

Thanks in Advance

I have tried the code as follows:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program P = new Program();


    string elasticSearchJson = P.GetElasticSearchQuery("Sales.State: CA");
    Console.WriteLine(elasticSearchJson);

    string jobcount = P.JobCount(elasticSearchJson);
}

public string GetElasticSearchQuery(string filter)
{
    string elasticSearchQuery = File.ReadAllText("ESCountQuery.json");
    dynamic workableElasticSearchQuery = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(elasticSearchQuery);

    workableElasticSearchQuery.query.query_string.query = filter;

    return workableElasticSearchQuery.ToString();
}

public string JobCount(string elasticSearchJson)
{
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("xxx")).DefaultIndex("xxx");

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<string>
    {
        Query = elasticSearchJson
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post on search templates. Please go through [my article here](https://kartheek91.github.io/2021/07/13/hands-on-elasticsearch-search-templates.html) as it will solve your problem.

I also a sample query using the NEST framework, it will solve your problem.

```
var client = new ElasticClient();
    
    var query = new SearchDescriptor<string>()
        .Query(q => q
            .QueryString(m => m
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Field(ff => ff.Sales.State)
                )
                .Query("{{query_string}}")
            )
        ));
        
    var template = client.Serializer.SerializeToString(query);
    
    client.PutSearchTemplate("template-name", ps => ps
        .Template(template)
    );
    
    var searchResponse = client.SearchTemplate<Question>(st => st
        .Index("posts")
        .Id("template-name")
        .Params(p => p
            .Add("query_string", "\"CA\"")  
        )
    );
```

Comment: Hi Kartheek,

Thanks for your response.

In my case, the index name remains the same and I just need to update the query string alone.

I have used elasticsearch rawquery options and it works for me.

Comment: Exact thing worked:
--------------------------->

var result = client.Count<Test>(s => s.Query(q => q.Raw(elasticSearchJson)));